# Why is getIcon() not returning the updated icon after setIcon(...)?

Tags: java, swing, icons, imageicon, tic-tac-toe

I am making a Tic Tac Toe game using modified JButtons. Right now I am stuck on determining if someone has won. The solution seems simple: check to see if three icons in a row are the same. When I click (take a turn in the game), the JButton is set with the proper image (X or O). However, when I later call getIcon() for the respective buttons to check if there was a winner, it returns "null," not the icon I previously set it as, even though the image in the game appears just fine. I think the issue lies within the order with which the program processes/runs; though, I may be completely wrong. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Code:

Main Class:

```
import javax.swing.*;


public class ticTacToeMain{

    public static void main(String[]args){

        boolean winner = false;

            ticTacToeBoard theBoard = new ticTacToeBoard();
            theBoard.setTitle("Tic Tac Toe");   
            theBoard.setSize(theBoard.getWidth(),theBoard.getHeight());
            theBoard.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            theBoard.setVisible(true);

            winner = theBoard.checkWinner(theBoard.buttons);
            if(winner == true)
                System.exit(0); //I have this only temporarily so that I know if it actually works  
    }

}
```

Board Class:

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.GridLayout;


public class ticTacToeBoard extends JFrame{

int w = 600;
int h = 600;
int turn = 0;
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
TTTButton buttons[]=new TTTButton[9];

public ticTacToeBoard(){
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
    for(int i=0; i<9; i++){
        buttons[i]=new TTTButton();
        panel.add(buttons[i]);
    }
    add(panel);
    panel.setVisible(true);
}
public int getWidth(){
    return w;
}
public int getHeight(){
    return h;
}

public boolean checkWinner(TTTButton[]buttonArray){
    if (buttonArray[0].getIcon() == buttonArray[1].getIcon() && buttonArray[0] == buttonArray[2].getIcon() && buttonArray[0] != null)
        return true;
    else if (buttonArray[3].getIcon() == buttonArray[4].getIcon() && buttonArray[3] == buttonArray[5].getIcon() && buttonArray[3] != null)
        return true;
    else if (buttonArray[6].getIcon() == buttonArray[7].getIcon() && buttonArray[6] == buttonArray[8].getIcon() && buttonArray[6] != null)
        return true;
    else if (buttonArray[0].getIcon() == buttonArray[3].getIcon() && buttonArray[0] == buttonArray[6].getIcon() && buttonArray[0] != null)
        return true;
    else if (buttonArray[1].getIcon() == buttonArray[4].getIcon() && buttonArray[0] == buttonArray[7].getIcon() && buttonArray[1] != null)
        return true;
    else if (buttonArray[2].getIcon() == buttonArray[5].getIcon() && buttonArray[0] == buttonArray[8].getIcon() && buttonArray[2] != null)
        return true;
    else if (buttonArray[0].getIcon() == buttonArray[4].getIcon() && buttonArray[0] == buttonArray[8].getIcon() && buttonArray[0] != null)
        return true;
    else if (buttonArray[2].getIcon() == buttonArray[4].getIcon() && buttonArray[0] == buttonArray[6].getIcon() && buttonArray[0] != null)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}


}
```

Button Class:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;


public class TTTButton extends JButton implements ActionListener{

static boolean winner = false;
static int turn = 0;
ImageIcon iconX;
ImageIcon iconO;

    public TTTButton(){
        iconX = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Aaron\\Pictures\\Logo_stx.png");
        iconO = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Aaron\\Pictures\\ohiostateO.jpg");
        this.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if (turn == 0){
            setIcon(iconX);
            turn+=1;

        }
        else if (turn == 1){
            setIcon(iconO);
            turn-=1;

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not calling `checkWinner(...)` within any event listener, but instead you're calling it only once on program creation:

```
public static void main(String[]args){

    boolean winner = false;

    ticTacToeBoard theBoard = new ticTacToeBoard();
    theBoard.setTitle("Tic Tac Toe");   
    theBoard.setSize(theBoard.getWidth(),theBoard.getHeight());
    theBoard.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    theBoard.setVisible(true);

    winner = theBoard.checkWinner(theBoard.buttons); // **** here ****
}
```

At this location **all the icons are in fact guaranteed to be null** -- they have to be since no button has yet been pressed.

The solution is simple -- don't call this method on program startup, but rather only call it from within a button's ActionListener.

Note that this program would be a great one to try to structure along M-V-C (model-view-controller) lines, to try to separate the program logic from the GUI. It would be a worthwhile exercise in terms of learning and in reducing code cyclomatic complexity.